# Unable to activate "DV360 Seller API". Keep getting "Insufficient permissions to check the enablement status of this product."

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api

I am trying to activate "DV360 Seller API" on Google cloud platform, but I keep getting  "Insufficient permissions to check the enablement status of this product." and I don't have the enable option available.
I also get this error when trying to create credentials.

This is a new user created for this purpose. Which permissions does this user need in order to be able to perform those operations?

Comment: Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.   Then edit your question include your code and describe any issues you are having with your current solution.  Links to documentation you have consulted and full error messages or stack traces can also be helpful.

Comment: Did you use this instruction https://developers.google.com/display-video/seller/guides/getting-started/setting_up_auth?

Comment: Yes, I did. I contacted Google DV360 with the account information and they added it to the allow list.

Comment: I think it's better to contact with the support team.

Answer (score 0):

You should have IAM role: **Service Usage Admin** (roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageAdmin). After that you will be able to activate the desired API